# How to create node from XML String then append to another node

Tags: xml, vba, msxml2, ixmldomdocument

I have a string variable containing XML that I would simply like to append to an IXMLDOMNode. Hilariously, this is the most primitive task, yet painfully unintuitive, in MSXML2. (I don't want to use XSLT).

My approach was:

```
Set xRoot = xDoc2.selectSingleNode("/ns:Root")  'destination parent
Set xNode = NodeFromXML(XMLstring)              'node to append
xRoot.appendChild xNode  'FAIL

----------------------------------------------

Private Function NodeFromXML(XMLstring As String) As IXMLDOMNode
'returns IXMLDOMNode of loaded XML string...
Dim Obj         As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
On Error GoTo handler
With Obj
   .async = False
   .loadXML XMLstring
   Set NodeFromXML = .selectSingleNode("/")
End With
handler:
End Function
```

The problem with this is that my *NodeFromXML* function produces a node that is of node type 'DOCUMENT' and thus cannot be appended to an ELEMENT type node.

How should I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

In the W3C DOM there are methods `importNode` (level 2) and `adoptNode` (level 3) that help to be able to insert a node owned by one document into another document.

I think MSXML doesn't usually care whether DOM nodes are owned by different documents, unless it is MSXML 6 and different threading models, where you then need the there available `importNode` method.

But for your sample, in the DOM, what you can insert into an element node like you selected as `xRoot`, with `appendChild`, is appropriate nodes e.g. element nodes, text nodes, comment nodes, processing instruction nodes. For your sample that means just return the `documentElement` so e.g. `Set NodeFromXML = Obj.documentElement`.

Then I would expect the `appendChild` to work.

If not, try e.g. `appendChild(xDoc2.importNode(xNode, True))`.